# PERL API error 500 server closed connection without sending any data back

Tags: perl

I am running a Perl API that uses `LWP::UserAgent` to post form data to a file.

Occasionally I receive this error on large files:

> "500 server closed connection without sending any data back"

The timeout doesn't seem to be the issue as its set to an astronomical number.

Comment: 500 isn't a timeout error, it's a server error. The server had issues while processing your request. Go check the logs on that server to figure out what happened.

Comment: 500 errors would have more details in the server's error log. look there to see what's blowing up.

Comment: Unfortunately checking the log is not a possibility as it is not mine, but are you certain this would be the server end causing it?

Comment: Any 5xx errors are by definition server-side errors: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error

Comment: And this only happens with large files?  It's possible that your script is taking too long to complete and so getting killed off by the host.  From Apache's perspective (as it's not party to the decision to kill off your process) it's just getting a premature end of script headers, and properly reports an internal server error.

Comment: no, this wouldn't be the server; LWP returns 500 with some errors that are detected on the client side, with appropriate error messages (like this one)

Answer (score 7):

If the response that you get has `Client-Warning` header, as seen in response below, then it is a tcp level error and response is produced by LWP client and not the server:

```
500 Server closed connection without sending any data back
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Thu, 19 Sep 2013 08:04:28 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding https://{host}/path.

example: http://localhost:6543/carnelian
ssh -v -N -L  6543:[remotehost]:[port]
result: error 500 server closed connection without sending any data back

example: https://localhost:6543/carnelian
ssh -v -N -L  6543:[remotehost]:[port]
It works.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'gopher':

```
# For a single scheme:
$ua->proxy('gopher', 'http://proxy.sn.no:8001/');
```

Comment: Why would the ancient gopher protocol make a difference and why do you think the server would even support it?